# Double quotes issue in bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, escape-characters

I have a shell script I am trying to get working. I need the output to be a certain way and I know I'm just not escaping the characters correctly.

script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
DATE=$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%M)
ELEMENTS="ele1,ele2,ele3"
TOPIC="dogs cats"
FILE="./$DATE.csv"
COMMAND="python /home/script.py"
$COMMAND $ELEMENTS "$TOPIC" | tee -a $FILE
```

What happens from set in the terminal when I run it is:

```
++ date +%Y-%m-%d-%M
+ DATE=2016-02-01-21
+ ELEMENTS=a list of elements
+ TOPIC='dogs cats'
+ FILE=./2016-02-01-21.csv
+ COMMAND='python /home/script.py'
+ python /home/script.py ele1,ele2,ele3 'dogs cats'
+ tee -a ./2016-02-01-21.csv
```

What I need it to be is "dogs cats" vs 'dogs cats'. The python command requires double quotes for multi word strings.

This is wheezy running on a raspberry pi.

Comment: I think `dogs cats` is correctly passed to the script as a multi word string.  Single quotes shown by `set -x` are always added to arguments with spaces just for clarification, they're not actually passed to the script.  How do you treat command line args in `script.py`?

Comment: the py script being called is not my own, but when given multiple strings without quotes, it treats each one as an _or_, with quotes it treats them as _and_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
TOPIC="dogs cats"
```

to

```
TOPIC='"dogs cats"'
```

to have `"` embedded inside the variable.

Comment: that yields:+ python /home/pi/script.py ele1,ele2,ele3 '"dogs cats"'
+ tee -a ./2016-02-01-57.csv

Comment: Isn't that what you want, given your comment above?

Comment: @RoninUTA You are confusing what you "see" from `set -x` as what "it is". The `'` are used to express the concept of "exactly this string", not that those single quotes are sent to the executed command.

Comment: You are absolutely correct! Thank you everyone !!!!!